# How to instantiate object from string using Linq New method and provide a constructor parameter?

Tags: .net, linq, lambda

How can I provide a constructor parameter when instantiating an object from string using Linq `New` method?

I do the following to instantiate the object without parameters, however I would like to provide one for my `DefaultWebRazorHostFactory` which requires a constructor parameter. Is this possible?

```
Dim factoryType As Type = TypeFactory(typeName)
Dim o as Func(Of WebRazorHostFactory) = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of WebRazorHostFactory))(Expression.[New](factoryType)).Compile()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a c# example:

```
Type type = typeof(SqlConnection);
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string));

var body = Expression.New(type.GetConstructor(new Type[] {typeof(string)}),param);
var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, SqlConnection>>(body, param).Compile();
```

Comment: Ok so we [used this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534318%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)..sorry i wasn't aware of that...so should i delete my answer..:(